# Can ladies take head bath after dark?

Tags: dharma-shastras

According to dharma shastras, are ladies allowed to take bath by pouring water on their head after dusk, in the dark ?

I heard someone say it is a bad thing, similar to ladies leaving their hair untied.

Comment: I think bathing in dark is not allowed for anyone male or females.

Comment: I have been told that many ladies do so for modesty reasons.

Comment: @Yogi is right. Taking head bath in normal circumstances is discouraged after dark. Exceptions may be when news of death reaches the lady and her asoucha is cleansed by a headbath. Not all asouchas are cleansed so easily, though.

Answer (score 3):

Under normal circumstances, they are **not allowed** to take head bath nor take bath after sunset (including during and after dusk).

> saśirā vamajjanam apsu varjayet || 7 || 
> 7. One should not submerge the head together with the body [in bathing],
>
> astamite ca snānam || 8 || 
> 8. And [one should avoid] bathing after sunset.
>
> Apastamba Sutra 1.11.32

Later, Apastamba says this:

> śanair apo- ‘abhyaveyād abhighnann abhimukham ādityam udakam upaspṛśet || 13 || 
> 13. He shall enter the water slowly, and bathe without beating it [with his
> hand], **his face turned towards the sun**.
>
> iti sarvatra-udaka upasparśana vidhiḥ || 14 || 
> 14. This rule of bathing is **valid for all** [castes and orders].
>
> Apastamba Sutra 2.9.22

The rule for bathing while looking towards the sun (which assumes it is there) applies to everyone.

Comment: "In the days of Apastamba there were no bathrooms and all bathing took place in the local river which was a dangerous place after sunset."  -- This commentary is non sense. I have myself verified a lot of times that bath after sunset does not "purify" you like the way it does before sunset. It has nothing to do with where bathrooms are located now or where they were located in the past. Achamana in contrast purifies both in night and in day.

Comment: Bathing after sunset is allowed only during certain times like when there is a Grahana.

Comment: @Rickross For first comment: Ok thanks for info, I have removed. For second comment: Yes I said “under normal circumstances” bathing after sunset is not allowed. Apastamba mentions some instances where it is allowed.

Comment: Yes, thanks. You can see this answer too: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31657/4732