# Does Hinduism give preference to scriptural injunctions over own logical thought in day to day activities?

Tags: scripture, belief

We face many situations in our daily life. Starting from morning to night. We also face situations where we have to make decisions to get out of those situations. Should we follow what the prescription from the scriptures without thinking about much or use our intellect which says to be logical caused by attaining education (not necessarily Vedas and smritis) after a thought process thinking pros and cons.

For example : After returning from my work, I feel my body is smelly due to sweat and I should take a bath. But [the time prescribed](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31465/5212) has already past. And many more situations like this.

In such cases, should we give importance to our logical thought caused by education or blindly follow the scriptural injunctions which say what to do?  Does Hinduism discourage own thought?

I'm not talking about  shabda pramana or pratyaksha pramana to prove something. I am talking about which should be followed in daily activities.

Please refrain from giving own thoughts and advises in comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Hindu morality come from scripture or is it the other way round?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18744/does-hindu-morality-come-from-scripture-or-is-it-the-other-way-round)

Comment: @Turiyanāth how is this question a duplicate? It doesn't seem connected to the referenced duplicate question.

Comment: if we can disregard scripture for personal opinion, what is the point of scripture ? btw, there are several shukshma within shastras, based on circumstances, intent etc. and more exceptions than rules, which we may not be aware of. for such known/unknown transgressions, there are many prayaschittas as well - even sandhya-vandana mantras has these. the point we should drive home is that under no circumstance should we bring down the ideal just because it doesn't suit the times, or we're unable/unwilling to follow it. **'Try our best. Repent for the rest'**

Comment: @sarvabhouma i was currently reading yoga vasistha and it says that person should be thoughtfull.All ill acts and mental pain originates from non thinking only.Even indra dev says in mahabharata to yudhisthira that person should think and then act.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, what is pleasing/acceptable to oneself is also one of the means of Dharma just like the scriptures (or the scriptural injunctions) are.

Because, [Manu Smriti 2.12](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145585.html) says:

> वेदः स्मृतिः सदाचारः स्वस्य च प्रियमात्मनः ।
>  एतच्चतुर्विधं
>   प्राहुः साक्षाद् धर्मस्य लक्षणम् ॥ १२ ॥
>
> vedaḥ smṛtiḥ sadācāraḥ **svasya ca priyamātmanaḥ** |
>   etaccaturvidhaṃ prāhuḥ sākṣād dharmasya lakṣaṇam || 12 ||
>
> The Veda, the Smṛti, the Practice of cultured Men, **and what is
>   agreeable to oneself**—these directly constitute the fourfold means of
>   knowing Dharma.—(12)

**UPDATE:**

> which should be our preference? Can I take a decision which is
>   agreeable to me which is not sanctioned in the scripture. There is an
>   example I gave you in the question.

The example given in the question is this:

> For example : After returning from my work, I feel my body is smelly
>   due to sweat and I should take a bath. But the time prescribed has
>   already past. And many more situations like this.

What we need to understand here is that when scriptures say bathing in night is forbidden then that injunction refers to a "ritual bathing" which is aimed at attaining ritual purity.

A ritualistic bath is preceded by a Sankalpa. It is done while holding the Kusha grass in hand. It is done while submerging the head in a water body. Therefore, the bath that we take in a shower cabin in today's time is not really a ritual.

One has to see the following Parashara Smriti verses:

> 21. Bathing in the daytime, while being purified by the rays of the sun, is the approved form of bathing. **Bathing at night is not approved
>       unless when the Rahu is visible in the heavens.**
> 22. Bathing, making of gifts, austerities, and burnt-offerings, may be made at night when an eclipse is seen. Night otherwise is impure ;
>       **therefore night is to be shunned in performing rites**.

So, when bathing is ritual it is forbidden to be done at night.

Now, what is the reason that a ritualistic bath is forbidden in the night?

> 23. The Maruts, the Vasus, the Rudras, the Aditya, and other deities, all disappear with the moon. Therefore, gifts are not proper at night.

The Vedic deities are said to disappear at night and that is why rituals, whether it is making gifts (charity) or even bathing, are disapproved during that time.

Now, does that mean if a hungry man comes to you during night giving him food is an act of sin? No way..  Because it is not a formal and ritual charity that you are making here.

The same logic applies when it comes to a bath that is a necessity of the body and mind and not a ritualistic formality.

If the body is sweaty and dirty after a soccer session (say) at night then there is nothing wrong in having a bath. Because, one should aim at remaining pure all the time and sweat is one the impurities of the body.

> Manu Smriti 5.135. Oily exudations, semen, blood, (the fatty substance
>   of the) brain, urine, faeces, the mucus of the nose, ear-wax, phlegm,
>   tears, the rheum of the eyes, and sweat are the twelve impurities of
>   human (bodies).

> He should not do so while he or the person greeted is seated, lying
>   down, or impure. **If he is able, he should not remain impure even for
>   a moment** (A 1.11.32 n.) - **Baudhayana Dharmasutras 1.3.13**

Comment: which should be our preference? Can I take a decision which is agreeable to me which is not sanctioned in the scripture. There is an example I gave you in the question.

Comment: Check your answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18744/does-hindu-morality-come-from-scripture-or-is-it-the-other-way-round). A great philosopher having guru-chandal yoga once said - "Understanding of contradictions is the beginning of wisdom." ;)

Comment: I think this answer illuminates some excellent points. There is an underlying expectation, as I have understood it, that knowledge is not truly known until the knower has digested it. Part of that process is to be able to find the harmony in apparently contradictory ideas. This maps back to prasthana-trayi, one of which is sruti but we are also able to apply pratyaksa and anumana. This applies in day-to-day situations as well as in analyzing the proper way according to dharma.