# Are there any references in scriptures related to respecting our own understanding(સમજ)?

Tags: scripture, mind, buddhi

Should scriptures be called out for every matters?

Comment: you're going to get answers of the form "Accept only those scriptures that are acceptable to you". There is an ancient term for such philosophies - called Charvaka (Charu+Vaak = Sweet+Words). Following that siddhanta is a sure-fire way into Naraka. If these philosophies are true, then a thief can say "the Indian Penal Code is opposite to my beliefs and understandings, so I reject it". Think of Shastras as a user manual. It simply gives you cause and effect. If you turn knob right, machine will work. If you turn it left, it will break. You are free to not read the manual, and try things out.

Comment: Not exactly understanding but may be conscience (viveka). That verse (Manu 2.12) is given in my answer (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31657/4732). Note that it can be grossly misunderstood if taken out of context.

Comment: Do you agree with closure of your question? Since I have a gold badge of "scripture" my vote closed the question immediately. If you don't agree post a comment tagging me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is such a thing in our scriptures.

> Bhishma said, ‘He is said to be conversant with duty who knows duty as
> depending on four foundations.’
>
> [four foundations, i.e., as laid down
> in the Vedas; as laid down in the Smritis; as sanctioned by ancient
> usage and customs; **and as approved by the heart or one’s own
> conscience**.]

**Mahabharata, Santi Parva, Section CXXXII**

Lord Krishna said,

> '...Reflecting on this whole teaching **do as you think fit**.'

**Gita 18.63**

Neither Sruti, nor Smriti, nor tradition can override one's conscience.

Example:

> 'The women are not entitled to utter the Veda mantras ..'

**Agni Purana 152.11**

We cannot accept such a discriminatory and arbitrary attitude and this verse should be rejected.

Comment: Is there any scriptual reference of Neither Sruti, nor Smriti, nor tradition can override one's conscience?